# LazyLoadImages loads everything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement `LazyLoadingImage`, unfortunately, every image is loaded no matter if I scroll onto it or not.

```
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";

{products.map((product) => (
    <div>
      <Link to={`/prints/${product._id}`}>
        <LazyLoadImage
          className="w-full"
          src={product.image}
          alt={product.name}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: try to add {index, product} in your array, and the give attr key="{index}"

Comment: loading="lazy"  and this is so far